# Dropshadow with image blur UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, dropshadow

I would like to get the result of the Windows video app blur. I did an image with a dropshadow, but giving the dropshadow only one color. Is it possible with win2d or other to get this result ,then use the image for the DropShadow?

[image]

My MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="grid"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets/image.jpg"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(grid).Compositor;
    var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    spriteVisual.Size = new Vector2(200, 200);
    var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
    dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
    dropShadow.BlurRadius = 10;
    dropShadow.Color = Colors.Orange;
    spriteVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(grid, spriteVisual);
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the effect you're trying to do?  You just want to blur the whole thing?  What is the windows video app blur?

Comment: In the Windows Movie and TV App, in the personal page, when you move the mouse over an item, then on a thumbnail (thumbnail preview) the shadow backdrop is not a single color, but is derived from the image that is the effect I would like to achieve.

Comment: I see, that is a pretty neat effect.  There may be a way to do it using the Composition API like you're trying to do but I don't know what it is.  However, you could easily put a blurred, offset and partially opaque copy of the image behind it and have it only visible on pointerover event.  I'll add it as an answer, maybe someone provides a better one using the Composition API.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started in creating the effect you're looking for.  You'll need the UWP Community Toolkit library which is sponsored by Microsoft.  It has this amazing animation syntax you'll see below, and it uses the Composition API under the hood.  Tweak the blur, scale and fade as you see fit.

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited">
        <Image x:Name="imageBackdrop" Source="Assets/image.jpg" Opacity="0"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets/image.jpg"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations;

private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{    
  imageBackdrop.Fade(0.5f, 50).Scale(1.1f, 1.1f,0,0,0).Blur(75, 0).Offset(0, 20, 0).Start();
}

private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{    
  imageBackdrop.Opacity = 0;
}
```

EDIT: Easier to just scale in XAML using a container.  Also adding an opacity effect to the same element as a blur effect seems to make the blur effect cap out at a very low BlurAmount.  Use something like this in combination with an opacity mask or something to darken it and feather the edges:

```
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = imageBackdrop;
    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);
    var compositor = visual.Compositor;

    var effect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("EffectSource"),
        BlurAmount = 50f,
        BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Soft,
    };

    var blurEffectFactory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(effect, new[] { effect.Name + "." + nameof(effect.BlurAmount) });
    var brush = blurEffectFactory.CreateBrush();
    var destinationBrush = compositor.CreateBackdropBrush();
    brush.SetSourceParameter("EffectSource", destinationBrush);

    var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)(element.RenderSize.Width), (float)(element.RenderSize.Height));
    sprite.Brush = brush;
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(element, sprite);
    imageBackdropContainer.Opacity = 1;
}

private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    imageBackdropContainer.Opacity = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please insert an image of the result obtained?

Comment: Apologies I did not include a brush to round and feather the edges so it looks very bad.  Also I notice there is some kind of bug or limitation when applying opacity and blur to the same UIElement and that when doing so the blur effect is very minimal no matter how high you set it.  Perhaps applying one effect to an enclosing Grid would work. You get the idea. Compositor.CreateDropShadow() likely won't work AFAIK. Use a copy of the image and filter it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to offset the same image with a lower `Opacity` to implement the similar effect using the [CompositionSurfaceBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionSurfaceBrush).

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(grid).Compositor;
    var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    spriteVisual.Size = new Vector2(215, 215);

    var brush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush();
    LoadedImageSurface _loadedSurface = LoadedImageSurface.StartLoadFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.jpg"));
    brush.Surface = _loadedSurface;

    spriteVisual.Opacity = 0.1f;
    spriteVisual.Brush = brush;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(grid, spriteVisual);
}
```

And this is the effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`DropShadowPanel` from Windows Community Toolkit should achieve what you want. At least I used this to implement that. Then use VisualStateManager to set it's visibility to True when PointerOver.